# (rails) script/plugin install - what does it means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, installation, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have stupid question, on which can't find answer.
I tried to install Selenium from https://github.com/paytonrules/selenium-on-rails
they say:

> To install:
>
> Install Selenium on Rails: script/plugin install

where should I write these words?
in terminal from rails root - no effect.

I even don't have folder "plugin" in folder "script", and creating doesn't help.
Please, clerify this question for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Rails 2.x way of installing a plugin.

If you are using Rails 3.x you need to install plugins with `rails plugin install`

Comment: Vendored plugins are deprecated in Rails 3.2, and removed entirely in Rails 4.  You should probably see if there's a way to get that functionality into your Gemfile. Or in your lib/ folder:  [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released/)

Comment: Agreed.  It looks like the installation doc for the Selenium on Rails project was written for Rails 2.x